# Boxes and arrows with text over them (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am trying to use TikZ to get two boxes with arrows between each other like this (including the text above and below the arrows), but I don't have any experience with it so I keep failing to do so.

Thanks in advance for any solution you might have! I will definitely try it out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! It is always appreciated if you show us what you have so far, in the form of a minimal working example. I.e. a self-sufficient document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that we can compile without modifications. In some cases it's entirely necessary to understand the problem, and in cases like this it can lower the barrier for those able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only images ... their placement in text is up to you :)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm and 30mm,
box/.style = {draw, minimum height=12mm, align=center},
sy+/.style = {yshift= 2mm}, 
sy-/.style = {yshift=-2mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {align=center}
                        ]
\node (n1) [box]             {\textbf{Party A}\\(fixed rate payer)};                        
\node (n2) [box,right=of n1] {\textbf{Party B}\\(fixed rate payer)};
%
\draw[thick,-Triangle]  
    ([sy+] n1.east) to [above,"Nation $\times$ fixed\\ mortality rate"] ([sy+] n2.west);
\draw[thick,-Triangle, dashed]  
    ([sy-] n2.west) -- ([sy-] n1.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm and 44mm,
box/.style = {draw, minimum height=12mm, inner xsep=3mm, align=center},
sy+/.style = {yshift= 2mm},
sy-/.style = {yshift=-2mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {align=center},
     font = \sffamily
                        ]
\node (n1) [box]             {Aegon\\(Hedger)};
\node (n2) [box,right=of n1] {Deutche\\Bank};
%
\draw[thick,-Triangle, dashed]
    ([sy+] n2.west) to [above,"Floating payments' linked\\
                              to \textbf{realized} mortality rates"] ([sy+] n1.east);
\draw[very thick,-Triangle]
    ([sy-] n1.east) to[below,"Fixed payments"] ([sy-] n2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```